# How to implement azure MSAL/oauth and get access tokens on a fullstack application (reactjs, python flask)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, oauth, msal

I need some advice on how to implement microsoft oauth using msal-browser on frontend react and msal for python on a flask backend

The use case for the application is that only logged in users within the same organization tenant can access the application and also need valid tokens to be able to call apis (flask backend)

I have managed to set up and configure everything needed on entra ID(azure active directory) and got a `PublicClientApplication` instance working on the reactjs frontend, including getting authorization code from the redirect, but now i am stuck on what to do next

i attempted to pass the authorization code directly to my backend through calling an api endpoint on the flask application,  which then next uses a `ConfidentialClientApplication` and `acquire_token_by_authorization_code` method to attempt getting access token, but I get the following error:`"AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE"`
looking at the documentation doesn't tell me anything about how i should be resolving this issue and if i am even implementing this correctly

i took a look at the documentation for other methods in `ConfidentialClientApplication` and saw the method `acquire_token_on_behalf_of` see: https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.ConfidentialClientApplication and i am wondering if i should be using this method instead

I am new to oauth/PCKE/authorization code flow so any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

msal config on reactJS(using msal-browser):

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: clientId,
        authority: authority,
        redirectUri: "/auth",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE || isEdge || isFirefox
    }
};
```

flask:

```
@app.route("/getAToken", methods=["GET","POST"])
def authorized():
    #get code from POST json body
    req_body = request.get_json()
    code = req_body["code"]
    #intialize empty result
    result = None
    #get access token
    if code:
        result=azure.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            code,
            scopes=["User.Read"],
            redirect_uri="http://localhost:5173/auth",
            )
```

on App registrations my redirect URI is configured as `http://localhost:5173/auth` for SPA application